# Does assembly "syscall" print to console?

Tags: assembly, mips

I've been staring at this code for two hours trying to figure out why it won't print my string to the screen. Syscall is the operation to print something to console right? What could be wrong.

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "I'm going insane 5:  "
.text
main:      

ori $2, $0, 4
lui $1, 4097 
ori $4, $1, 0
syscall


jr $ra
add $0, $0, $0
```

it compiles and runs but nothing gets printed...

Comment: You're running this in MARS or SPIM, right?  https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html.  Are you sure your string data is actually at `0x10010000`? Use the debugger, and/or check what you get from `la $a0, prompt`.  Also, `OR` with immediate zero does nothing, you might as well just `lui $a0, 0x1001`.

Comment: Nope, it was at 4096. Thank you too, got confused with "ori $4, $1, 0"